# Word for consolidating a dataset to a single type

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

I believe there is a single word that represents what I am trying to say, but for the life of me I can’t remember it.

I have a line graph of amounts vs. time. The amounts are for different currencies. I then have a derivative graph where all the amounts are in one currency.

> The second graph is [blanked] to the same currency.

I thought of *normalized*, but it doesn't feel quite right. The idea behind this word is to take a disparate dataset and to make it the same.

Comment: *Refactored* is certainly wrong.  I’m not so sure that *normalized* is necessarily wrong, though.  But do you  mean converted or scaled?

Comment: @tchrist - converted is true, but I believe there is a word that is more representative of the action. More along the lines of taking an entire set and making them the same. Normalize is close, but I think there is a better word yet.

Comment: Not sure if I've fully understood but *relative*?

Comment: @spiceyokooko - thank you for this suggestion spicey. Not quite what I was looking for. I updated my question with a fill in the blank sentence example. Relative doesn't quite fit the bill - `The second graph is relative to the same currency.`

Comment: *Pinned*, perhaps?

Comment: I see, so you're *somethinginging* to the same currency. Factoring?

Comment: I'm afraid I too think it's *normalized*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about *exchanged*?

Graph 1 represents each series in the local currency.

Graph 2 represents each currency exchanged to [reporting currency here] using the [datasource] rates as of [datestamp].

Comment: I ended up ducking my initial question and going with this solution.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you are thinking of *[standardized](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/standardize?s=t)*, to bring to a standard measurement.

Comment: This has potential. Will see what other suggestions come through.

Answer (score 2):

You used it in your title.  I like:

> The second graph is **consolidated** to the same currency.

As with any business artifact, its creation is driven by the intended audience and context.  (Is it to the Board of Directors?  Is it coming from accountants?  Is it to be a standard internal report that has cross-dependent use as a data source? Etc.)  That said, simplicity is best.  Letting the graph speak for itself.  Simply use, “In dollars” as a footnote descriptor to the graph.  (Or “Euros” or whatever the audience expects.)

If within a paragraph you need to talk about the graph just say “the consolidated view below.”  Where you get into trouble is when you manipulate source data vs. the representation.  Then you might include a footer with explicit reference to conversion rate source and date (again depending on proper exactitude of context and use).  You probably don’t need to give currency exchange rate source and date, but you do need to make sure the currency values are concurrent, and not – for example – 6 months apart.

“Normalized” is a reserved word in database circles for database design.  “Massaged” data is used quite often but not about financial data.  (E.g. J. Smith = John Smith, [or does it?])  “Massaged data” intuitively includes rounding errors and such, but it can be pejorative if not careful on a hard report.  “Standardized” is rarely used, and can misrepresent – as if all local currencies are inferior to the Euro/Dollar/Yen standard, or whatever.  So I would just use “the consolidated view below”.  Financial statements talk of “consolidated” funds across global entities.

Answer (score 1):

I am also a fan of **normalized**, but here is another option: When one set of data is translated into coordinate system, we sometimes say the data is *projected*. This is more commonly used when converting from a 3-dimensional system to a 2-dimensional system, such as using a flat map to represent a globe (consider the [Mercator Projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection))

Answer (score 0):

In programming, there is a technical term for that, cast. But I don't think that will convey meaning to a non-technical crowd.
I was a fan of normalized.

Maybe adjusted? resolved? translated? rendered?